# Remove wrapping div and ul from output of wp_nav_menu

Tags: customization, menus

I am using the new menu system of Wordpress, and here is the result of wp_nav_menu()

```
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
   <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
   <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type current-menu-item page_item page-item-21 current_page_item menu-item-28"><a href="http://www.bemang.com/">Trang nhà</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-29"><a href="http://www.bemang.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-30"><a href="http://www.bemang.com/gioi-thieu/">Giới thiệu</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

What I want is only this:

```
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type current-menu-item page_item page-item-21 current_page_item menu-item-28"><a href="http://www.bemang.com/">Trang nhà</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-29"><a href="http://www.bemang.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-30"><a href="http://www.bemang.com/gioi-thieu/">Giới thiệu</a></li>
```

No, wrapping div or ul, I have been trying to few ways and google around but no result :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The wrapping div is easy. When you use `wp_nav_menu()`, add this argument: `'container' => false`

For the `<ul>` element, there's an argument called `'items_wrap'`. See [woodchucky's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/remove-wrapping-div-and-ul-from-output-of-wp-nav-menu/13347#13347) for more info on that one (and upvote it!).

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It works now. I was not familiar with PHP and did not know that I need to put the add_filter to the functions.php.

Comment: That still doesn't explain how to remove the div, which rather wraps up the wrap_class explained above. The container argument set to false doesn't work.

Comment: If the `container` argument doesn't work, that means you're not using `wp_nav_menu`. You're probably running the fallback cb, which defaults to `wp_page_menu()`, by failing to specify either a menu, or a menu location with an assigned menu.

Answer (score 34):

`wp_nav_menu()` accepts an undocumented parameter

['items_wrap' => '`<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>`'](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L141)

This is executed by:
[`$nav_menu .= sprintf( $args->items_wrap, esc_attr( $wrap_id ), esc_attr( $wrap_class ), $items );`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L226)

you can play around with the sprintf arguments

ex: 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' would remove the wrapping `<ul>` tag

Comment: Heh, cool! And welcome to WPSE @woodchucky!

Answer (score 7):

For outputting only li's add this to wp_nav_menu array:

```
'container'      => '',
'items_wrap'    => '%3$s',
```

Answer (score 3):

`'container' => false` was failing for me because I was specifying a not existing `'theme_location'` and `'menu'`. It worked as soon as I fixed this.

Solution from: [wordpress.org/support](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-the-div-and-ul-tags-from-wp_nav_menu-function?replies=24#post-2079864)

Answer (score 1):

To filter out the wrapping div:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'prefix_nav_menu_args');
function prefix_nav_menu_args($args = ''){
    $args['container'] = false;
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2021

Tested and Working ✔

### To remove `<div>`

Use `container => false` or `container => ''` inside `wp_nav_menu`.

```
wp_nav_menu( 
    array( 
        'container' => false
    ) 
);
```

#### Still not working?

Do not add `theme_location` to your `wp_nav_menu`. If you do you will still see the `<div>` container.

```
wp_nav_menu( 
    array( 
        'container' => false,
        'theme_location' => 'Primary Menu'
    ) 
);
```

### To remove the `<ul>`

If you want to remove the `<ul>` wrapper, use this. Based on @Mill answer.

```
wp_nav_menu( 
    array( 
        'container' => '',
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
    ) 
);
```

#### If you need control on `<ul>` elements

If you want to retain all elements inside the `<ul>` from orignal WordPress `id` and `class` use this `'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'` based on @woodchucky answer.

```
wp_nav_menu( 
    array( 
        'container' => '',
        'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
    ) 
);
```