# Primery Menu Configuration problem

Tags: menus

I am writing below code.

```
$values = array(
       'theme_location'  => 'primary',
       'menu'            => 'efgh',
       'container'       => 'div',
       'container_class' => 'xyz',
       'container_id'    => 'pqr',
       'menu_class'      => 'menu_123',
       'menu_id'         => 'mno',
       'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="mouse_123" class="rat_456">Laptop</ul>'
);

wp_nav_menu( $values );
```

And getting below out put.

```
<nav>
    <div class="menu_123">
      <ul>
          <li class="page_item page-item-27"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=27">Bucket</a></li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2">Jug</a></li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=19">Cup</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

I would like to get output like below.

```
  <nav>
    <div class="menu_123">
      <ul class="my_class" id="my_id">
          <li class="page_item page-item-27"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=27">Bucket</a></li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2">Jug</a></li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-19"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=19">Cup</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks @vlood. I am trying a lot but I could not push any `class` or `id` to `ul`. I am updating my post.

**First UPDATE**

In my `fucntion.php` file

```
register_nav_menu( 'primary-menu', __( 'Primary Menu' ) );
```

In my `header.php` file

```
<nav>
 <?php 
   wp_nav_menu( 
     array(
       'container' => false,
       'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
       'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
     )); 

 ?>
</nav>
```

I am getting output like below.

```
<nav>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
           <li class="page_item page-item-27">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=27">Bucket</a>
          </li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-2">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=2">Mug</a>
          </li>
          <li class="page_item page-item-19">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=19">Jug</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I tried several ways but could not solve the problem

**Second UPDATE**

I found an interesting issue in Twenty Fourteen Theme

In `header.php` of Twenty Fourteen Theme

```
                   `<?php 
                        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary') ); 
                    ?>`
```

In `functions.php` of Twenty Fourteen Theme

`// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in two locations.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary'   => __( 'Top primary menu', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'secondary' => __( 'Secondary menu in left sidebar', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    ) );`

Output of Twenty Fourteen Theme.

`<nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">
      <div class="menu-mouse-container">
         <ul id="menu-mouse" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-26">
                <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25">
                <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=19">Mouse</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
       </div>

</nav>`

How is it possible to place `id` like `menu-mouse` and `class` like `menu` in `ul` ??

Answer (score 0):

For the ul part you should use this:

```
'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
```

%3$s is a placeholder for the list items, so you shouldn't change it to "Laptop" as you have done.

These are the parameters for the id and the class, that need to go together with items_wrap:

```
'menu_class'      => 'menu_123',
'menu_id'         => 'mno',
```

Why it works like this? Answer is here:

[Remove wrapping div and ul from output of wp_nav_menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/remove-wrapping-div-and-ul-from-output-of-wp-nav-menu/13347#13347)

Comment: Thanks @vlood. But your solution is not working.

Comment: My bad, try with %3$s instead of %1$s :)

Comment: Thanks @vlood. This time I tried. 

`$values = array(
                   'theme_location'  => 'primary',
                   'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="my_id" class="my_class">%3$s</ul>'
           );

           wp_nav_menu( $values );`



But result was as previous. So far I could not push any `class` or `id` in `ul`.

Thanks

Comment: Damn, it's my fault again. I tested it and it works when you use it like this:

'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'

Then it will get menu_id and menu_class in the %1$s and %2$s placeholders. I'm now updating the original answer with this.

Comment: Okay, I did according updates in the answer - you need to define these, if you want them in the ul: 'menu_class' and 'menu_id'

Comment: Thanks **@vlood** for your reply. This time I tried like this 

`wp_nav_menu( 
                   array(
                       'container' => false,
                       'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
                       'menu_class'      => 'menu_123',
                       'menu_id'         => 'mno',
                       'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
                       ));` But the result as like previous.

Comment: Actually I tired a lot to place `class` or `id` to `ul`. But could not succeed so far. Could you guess anything wrong regarding this?? Where could be the problem ?? Could you help me with some executed code example or any theme where this is implemented ??

Comment: Using your code on a random theme it works when I remove "theme_location" parameter. If you need to specify your menu, use "menu" => "Main Header Menu" instead, where the  value is the label of the menu, defined in register_nav_menus (usually in functions.php of your theme).

Please let me know if this works for you, and if not, I'll upload some sample theme in github or somewhere else for you to see and test.

Comment: Thanks **vlood**. Finally it worked. This time I followed your this instruction (Using your code on a random theme it works when I remove "theme_location" parameter). I removed `'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',` this parameter. But why it was not working before?? **Thanks for your long patience**.

Comment: If you are asking why my suggestions didn't work at first - because I didn't test it directly with your code, but a minimal combination of the three parameters (menu_class, menu_id and items_wrap).

Comment: No, I am not asking about that. I am asking that "Why is it working while I removed `theme_location' => 'primary-menu'`??" Is it harmful to add `theme_location' => 'primary-menu'` ?? What is the responsibility of `theme_location' => 'primary-menu'`??

Comment: I can't really find a specific reason for theme_location to break items_wrap effect. I guess looking in the code will give you an answer to this...